# Chaining async methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm attempting to chain together a few async methods I've created and I believe there is some fundamental misunderstanding on my part about how this works

Here's a representation of my code:

```
public async Task<bool> LoadFoo()
{
    return await Foo.ReadAsync("bar").ContinueWith((bar) =>
    {
        Foo.ReadAsync("baz").ContinueWith((baz) =>
        {
            Foo.ReadAsync("qux").ContinueWith((qux) =>
            {
                return true;
            });

            return true;
        });

        return true;
    });
}

public void LoadEverything()
{
    LoadFoo().ContinueWith((blah) =>
    {
        OtherLoadMethod();
    });
}
```

Now I was expecting when `LoadEverything()` was called that all of the `ReadAsync` methods in `LoadFoo ("bar", "baz" and "qux")` would run and complete, and after they all completed then the `.ContinueWith` in `LoadEverything` would run so that `OtherLoadMethod()` wouldn't execute until the "bar", "baz" and "qux" `ReadAsync` methods finished.

What I am actually seeing is that `LoadFoo` gets called and then `OtherLoadMethod` starts to run before getting to the final completion in `LoadFoo` (the `ContinueWith` of the "qux" `ReadAsync`).

Can someone help clear up my misunderstanding here? Why wouldn't the execution of `OtherLoadMethod` wait until `ReadAsync("qux")` finishes and returns true?

Comment: Don't use `ContinueWith`; use `await` instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why wouldn't execution of OtherLoadMethod wait until ReadAsync("qux") finishes and returns true?

Because that's how `await` works. The continuations you register are just that: *continuations*. They are not executed synchronously in the current method. You are telling the framework that *when the current task completes*, the continuation should be executed. The `Task` object returned by `ContinueWith()` allows you to observe the completion if and when it happens. There would be no need to even return a `Task` object, if the `ContinueWith()` method blocked until the continuation was executed.

Likewise, the `Task<bool>` returned by your `LoadFoo()` method represents the overall completion of the method, including the `await...ContinueWith()` that you're returning. The method returns prior to completion of the continuation, and callers are expected to use the returned task if they need to wait for the continuation to complete.

All that said, I don't understand why you're using `ContinueWith()` in the first place. You obviously have access to `await`, which is the modern, idiomatic way to handle continuations. IMHO, your code should look something like this (it's not clear why you're returning `Task<bool>` instead of `Task`, since the return value is only ever `true`, but I assume you can figure that part out yourself):

```
public async Task<bool> LoadFoo()
{
    await Foo.ReadAsync("bar");
    await Foo.ReadAsync("baz");
    await Foo.ReadAsync("qux");

    return true;
}

public async Task LoadEverything()
{
    await LoadFoo();
    await OtherLoadMethod();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. Just to make sure I understand correctly, await doesn't block the thread correct?  
If I was going to use continuations (for instance if I needed to use the return value of one of the methods), I wanted to understand this comment:  
"The method returns prior to completion of the continuation, and     callers are expected to use the returned task if they need to wait for the continuation to complete."  
Wouldn't calling LoadFoo().ContinueWith(...) be the caller waiting for the continuation to complete?

Comment: _"await doesn't block the thread"_ -- that is correct. `await` marks a point in the method where the method _may_ return (it won't if the awaitable expression has already completed), to be resumed (continued) at that point when the awaitable completes. The thread will either return to the caller at that point or continue executing the current method. Either way, the thread remains unblocked

Comment: _"Wouldn't calling LoadFoo().ContinueWith(...) be the caller waiting for the continuation to complete?"_ -- no. There's no wait there. The `ContinueWith()` simply registers a continuation and then returns the task object representing the completion of the continuation (which in turn can't complete until the original task does).

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `Unwrap`:

```
public async Task<bool> LoadFoo()
{
    await Foo.ReadAsync("bar")
        .ContinueWith(_ => Foo.ReadAsync("baz")).Unwrap()
        .ContinueWith(_ => Foo.ReadAsync("qux")).Unwrap();
    return true;
}

public async Task LoadEverything()
{
    await LoadFoo().ContinueWith(_ => OtherLoadMethod()).Unwrap();
}
```

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't. Mixing `await` and `ContinueWith` is asking for trouble.

Comment: Combining `await` and `ContinueWith` [could cause confusion](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html) because both continue on the current scheduler, but only the first continues on the current synchronization context. Also only the first unwraps the `AggregateException`s. The code in your answer may not be affected by these intricacies, but it has the problem of swallowing the possible exceptions of the `ReadAsync("bar")` and `ReadAsync("baz")` tasks. Only exceptions of `ReadAsync("qux")` will be observed.

Answer (score -1):

Did not expect the top solution in search engine was fixing a misunderstanding but not actually the solution of the topic itself.

Chaining call can make great context focus when developing, async is good, and it is better if you know what u r doing.

Code:

```
    //thanks for TheodorZoulias's review and input
public static class TaskHelper
{
    public static async Task<TOutput> ThenAsync<TInput, TOutput>(
        this Task<TInput> inputTask,
        Func<TInput, Task<TOutput>> continuationFunction,
        bool continueOnCapturedContext= true)
    {
        var input = await inputTask.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext);
        var output = await continuationFunction(input).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext);
        return output;
    }
    public static async Task<TOutput> ThenAsync<TInput, TOutput>(
        this Task<TInput> inputTask,
        Func<TInput, TOutput> continuationFunction,
        bool continueOnCapturedContext= true)
    {
        var input = await inputTask.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext);
        var output = continuationFunction(input);
        return output;

    }

    public static async Task<TInput> ThenAsync<TInput>(
        this Task<TInput> inputTask,
        Action<TInput> continuationFunction,
        bool continueOnCapturedContext= true)
    {
        var input = await inputTask.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext);
        continuationFunction(input);
        return input;
    }

    public static async Task<TInput> ThenAsync<TInput>(
        this Task<TInput> inputTask,
        Func<TInput, Task> continuationFunction,
        bool continueOnCapturedContext= true)
    {
        var input = await inputTask.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext);
        await continuationFunction(input).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext);
        return input;
    }




    public static async Task<TOutput> ThenAsync<TOutput>(
       this Task inputTask,
       Func<Task<TOutput>> continuationFunction,
       bool continueOnCapturedContext= true)
    {
        await inputTask.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext);
        var output = await continuationFunction().ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext);
        return output;
    }

    public static async Task ThenAsync(
        this Task inputTask,
        Action continuationFunction,
        bool continueOnCapturedContext= true)
    {
        await inputTask.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext);
        continuationFunction();
    }
}
```

Comment: *`bool configureAwait = false`* -- There are a couple of problems here. 1. The correct name of the parameter would be `continueOnCapturedContext`. `configureAwait` is meaningless IMHO. 2. The default value of the parameter is `true`. You have changed it into `false`, which will only serve at creating confusion. There is also a third problem: the example doesn't make a good job at demonstrating why is the `.Then` preferable to just `await`ing all these `SetTagValueAsync` calls the one after the other.

Comment: nice comments @TheodorZoulias  will add that changes to my code